# Sending current location through SMS

Tags: android, gps, location, sms

I'm trying to send an SMS of my current location although when I select the menu option, nothing happens.Here's my code: Any possible solutions on how I could get it working?

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_sms);


        final LocationManager mlocManager = (LocationManager)getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);

        final LocationListener mlocListener = new MyLocationListener();

        final Location location = mlocManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
        updateWithNewLocation(location);
        mlocManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, mlocListener);

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 21) {
            // Call some material design APIs here
        } else {
            // Implement this feature without material design
        }

    }


    public class MyLocationListener implements LocationListener

    {

        public void onLocationChanged(final Location location)
        {
            updateWithNewLocation(location);
        }
        public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

    }

    private void updateWithNewLocation(final Location location)
    {
        String latLongString;
        TextView myLocationText;
        myLocationText = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.myLocationText);
        String addressString = "No address found";

        if ( location != null )
        {
            final double lat = location.getLatitude();
            final double lng = location.getLongitude();

            latLongString = "Lat:" + lat + "\nLong:" + lng;
            final double latitude = location.getLatitude();
            final double longitude = location.getLongitude();
            final Geocoder gc = new Geocoder(this, Locale.getDefault());



            try
            {
                final List<Address> addresses = gc.getFromLocation(latitude, longitude, 4);
                final StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                if ( addresses.size() > 0 )
                {
                    final Address address = addresses.get(0);
                    for ( int i = 0; i < address.getMaxAddressLineIndex(); i++ )
                    {
                        sb.append(address.getAddressLine(i)).append("\n");
                    }
                    sb.append(address.getLocality()).append("\n");
                    sb.append(address.getPostalCode()).append("\n");
                    sb.append(address.getCountryName());
                }
                addressString = sb.toString();
            }
            catch ( final IOException e )
            {
            }
        }
        else
        {
            latLongString = "No location found";
        }
        myLocationText.setText("Your Current Position is:\n" +
                latLongString + "\n" + addressString);


    }





    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        MenuInflater inf = getMenuInflater();
        inf.inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        String tv1;
        TextView myLocationText;
        myLocationText = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.myLocationText);
        tv1= myLocationText.getText().toString();
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.sms_location:


                Intent sendIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
                sendIntent.putExtra("sms_body", tv1);
                sendIntent.setType("vnd.android-dir/mms-sms");
                startActivity(sendIntent);

                return(true);
            case R.id.email_location:
        /* Create the Intent */
                final Intent emailIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);

        /* Fill it with Data */
                emailIntent.setType("plain/text");
                emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, new String[]{"to@email.com"});
                emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Subject");
                emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, tv1);
                startActivity(Intent.createChooser(emailIntent, "Send mail..."));
                return(true);
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }}
```

This is my activity:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:paddingLeft="40dp"
    android:paddingRight="40dp"
    >

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/myLocationText"
        />



</LinearLayout>
```

My menu_main under menu has my items declared. I've really searched for a solution and I can't see anything on the log cat!

Comment: Are you getting any location?

Comment: @UmerAsif Yes, I'm getting a location

Answer (score 0):

Since you are getting your location. you can do this.

```
     public void onLocationChanged(final Location location)
    {
        updateWithNewLocation(location);
        SendSms(location);
    }

  public void SendSms(Location location){
       int phoneNo = "your phone number";
       double lattitude = location.getlatitude();
       double longitude = location.getLongitude();
      Similary any information you want
     then
     String message = "LAttiude "+lattitude+ " Longitude "+ "longitude"
      SmsManager smsManager = SmsManager.getDefault();
     smsManager.sendTextMessage("phoneNo", null, "sms message", null, null);
      }
```

Hope you figure it out,Remember to add this permission.

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS" />
```

Here is a tutorial for more inforemation.

http://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_sending_sms.htm

Comment: Thank so much! This actually helped me think in a different way and start an Intent to send the message! Thank You!